# Sinatra use thin webserver, how to make it show get "request-url"

Tags: ruby, sinatra, thin

In default sinatra webserver webrick, in dev mode, I can get following in stdout:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/May/2017:19:23:10 CST] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4
- -> /
```

but when i

```
set :server, "thin"
```

no request info is shown, how to open it? I hope show thin log in code, not `thin --debug` cli

**update**

here is full code:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  set :server, "thin"

  get '/' do
    "hello world"
  end

  get "/hello" do
    "drlow elloh"
  end
end

App.run!
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to do with thin, if you've not changed any configuration. Please add you main application file, sinatra, thin and rack versions.

**EXAMPLE**

A 2 minute rally

```
$ mkdir thiny
$ nano thiny/app.rb
$ cd thiny/
$ ruby app.rb
```

below lines are logs printed to std output, which i believe you are looking for.

```
== Sinatra (v2.0.0) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
Thin web server (v1.7.0 codename Dunder Mifflin)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:4567, CTRL+C to stop
127.0.0.1 - - [23/May/2017:16:04:08 +0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11 0.0111
127.0.0.1 - - [23/May/2017:16:04:17 +0400] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 200 11 0.0006
127.0.0.1 - - [23/May/2017:16:04:18 +0400] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 200 11 0.0011
127.0.0.1 - - [23/May/2017:16:04:19 +0400] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 200 11 0.0007
```

contents of app.rb

```
require 'sinatra'

set :server, "thin"

get '/' do
  "hello world"
end

get "/hello" do
  "drlow elloh"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution, just need add `set :logging, true`, here is full right code:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  set :server, "thin"
  set :logging, true

  get '/' do
    "hello world"
  end

  get "/hello" do
    "drlow elloh"
  end
end

App.run!
```